# Change localhost:8080 to my domain name in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, apache

I'm new in Geoserver and openlayers 3 and i want to publish my layers to be access from my subdomain (I want to change localhost:8080/geoserver to subdomain/geoserver)

i'm using

- Windows 7
- xampp
- Geoserver 2.8.1
- Openlayers 3

i found these lines but i don't know where to put it !

```
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On 
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow 
    Allow from all
</Proxy> 
ProxyPass /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver" 
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is slightly off-topic from GIS, but you'll need to place it in a [configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html) file that's read by apache.

Take a look at this simimilar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807600/apache-mod-proxy-configuring-proxypass-proxypassreverse-for-cross-domain-ajax

Comment: Thanks a lot i saw this post before but i was putting these lines in another file!